# Отправить по Bluetooth данные сенсора оси "х y z"?

Tags: java, bluetooth

Метод для  отправки данных:

```
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            connectedOutputStream.write(buffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Метод сенсора:

```
void getDeviceOrientation() {
    SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(r, null, valuesAccel, valuesMagnet);
    SensorManager.getOrientation(r, valuesResult);
    valuesResult[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valuesResult[0]);
    valuesResult[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valuesResult[1]);
    valuesResult[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(valuesResult[2]);
}
```

Как передать в байтовый поток `float valuesResult` по Bluetooth?

```
myThreadConnected.write(??);
```

Comment: Что то параметер в функцию write выглядит странно.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался )

```
 if(myThreadConnected!=null) {
        byte[] bytesToSend = format(valuesResult).getBytes();
        myThreadConnected.write(bytesToSend);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "***подтверждение: " + bytesToSend + "***");
    }
```